# Hide TextView on small screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide two TextViews on screens which have a smaller width than 500px.

I tried the following (this is not my complete code, but essential):

```
public class HeaderFooterFragment extends Fragment {
private TextView lable;
private TextView app;

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     lable = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lable);
     app = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.app);
// some code...

     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void setLableInvisible()
    {
        lable.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        app.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_footer, container, false);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;

        if(screenWidth < 500){
            setLableInvisible();
        }

        return fragmentView;
    }
}
```

My XML is:

```
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:id="@+id/lable"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/site_fontsize"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/site_paddingtop"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/site_paddingleft"
            android:textColor="@color/site_color"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:id="@+id/app"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/app_name_extra"
            android:textSize="@dimen/apptitlex_fontsize"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/apptitlex_paddingtop"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/apptitlex_paddingleft"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
```

When I start the app on a Smartphone with width 480px, I get a null object reference. If i start the app on a much more bigger screen, the app isn't crashing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get a null object reference .Post error log

Comment: Are you using 2 layout files in different values folders? This would explain why the views are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im' not sure that the view is created yet in OnActivityCreated, Try initialize your textView in OnCreateView

```
     lable = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lable);
     app = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.app);
```

Comment: ok nice, it is what i thought as the view is not created yet lable and app are still null if initialized in OnActivityCreated

Comment: First please check the flow via printing value of screenWidth and a message inside if condition, also handle with else because icase if() fails there should be a check.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this and delete onactivitycreated method

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_footer, container, false);
    lable = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lable);
         app = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.app);
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;

            if(screenWidth < 500){
                setLableInvisible();
            }

            return fragmentView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare **TextView** `onCreateView` instead of `onActivityCreated`  section

```
   View RootView; //Declare Global

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_footer, container, false);
        lable = (TextView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.lable);
        app = (TextView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.app);

       // Add Your staff here 

       return RootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
setLableInvisible();
```

Use below code to hide textview

```
app.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Similarly user it for second textview.
Thanks